# How do I write an iptables rule to limit Internet bandwidth usage of user or IP address

Tags: 12.04, scripts, iptables

How do I control or limit Internet bandwidth usage of users/computer/IP address in network with the help of [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) rules?

I have one static IP address which provides Internet (that is, WAN). I assigned this to eth0 and the local network IP address as 192.168.0.1 (LAN) which is eth1. This machine is acting as my gateway and [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server. If it is possible, can I use the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) to identify the machine?

Answer (score 1):

You basically asked two questions. The answers are:

1. No, you can't limit bandwidth using iptables. iptables is more of a firewall like thing which uses IP addressing as its mode of functioning. You can use the built-in program "tc" (traffic control) to fulfill your need of restricting the bandwidth. Many [ISPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) use tc to control their bandwidth. Usage of tc is complex, see the manpage of tc to get basic ideas.
2. You can use the command "arp -n" to see the [MAC addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of the connected hosts along with their IP addresses. So if you use your server as the gateway to the Internet then by using "arp -n" you'll see the MAC & IP addresses of all the devices of the local network currently connected to the server and also the MAC addresses & IP addresses of the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark , loop and drop packets in iptables. I have seen examples people does rate control with iptables.

```
# Limit packet traffic on a TCP or UDP port:
iptables -A INPUT -p $proto --destination-port $port --syn -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit $lim/s --limit-burst $lb -j ACCEPT

# Limit established/related packet traffic:
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit $lim/s --limit-burst $lb -j ACCEPT
```

from: https://serverfault.com/questions/340256/should-i-rate-limit-packets-with-iptables

Answer (score -1):

I use this to limit the traffic on my router for a range of IPs, but you need to have access to the router shell via ssh or telnet.

```
#enable the limitation
iptables -I FORWARD -m iprange --dst-range 192.168.1.50-192.168.1.70 -j DROP

iptables -I FORWARD -m iprange --dst-range 192.168.1.50-192.168.1.70 -m limit --limit 100/sec -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#disable it
iptables -D FORWARD 1
iptables -D FORWARD 1
```

Comment: Is your router running Ubuntu? This site is exclusively about Ubuntu and official derivatives.